# Vim using last searched for regex in :s command

Tags: vim

I am using slash for searching for stuff within vim. I'd like to use the regex that I used for search in a command (a substitute command to be exact). Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the subtitute command will use the last search if you do not specify it, so just use:

```
:s//<replacement>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the useful CTRL-R:

In the command line, if you are making a substitute command search with :, you can press CTRL-R and then / to insert the last search into the command line.

It's great that the opposite works too: If you are making a search with the slash, you can add your last command with CTRl-R and then :